# For statement increment and skip the rest of the code

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
for a in range(0,len(customer_name),1):

     url = "https://whatever_my_url_is.com/" + customer_name[a] + "/"
     
     try:
               page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     except:
               print("Cannot load page, bad URL.")
               a = a + 1

    rest of my code
```

What it currently does:

- Goes through each customer, one at a time, and loads their page.
- If the URL is bad, I get the `"Cannot load page, bad URL."` message.
- The rest of my code continues like normal.

What I want it to do is immediately stop what it's doing and move to the next `customer_name` on the list, **not** continue the rest of the code.

Comment: use ```continue``` -https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_continue_statement.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `continue`

```
for a in range(0,len(customer_name),1):

     url = "https://whatever_my_url_is.com/" + customer_name[a] + "/"
     
     try:
               page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     except:
               print("Cannot load page, bad URL.")
               continue

    rest of my code
```

Answer (score 1):

An else clause may be used within a try statement, see [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=try):

```
try1_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
               ("except" [expression] ":" suite)+
               ["else" ":" suite]
```

Therefore you can also write your code as follows:

```
for a in customer_name:
     url = 'https://whatever_my_url_is.com/{}/'.format(a)
     try:
               page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     except:
               print("Cannot load page, bad URL.")
     else:
        rest of my Code
```

Other improvements:

1. `range(start, stop, step)` may be written as `range(stop)` if start is 0 and step is 1.
2. You may use a sequence item directly.
   instead of

   ```
   for index in range(len(sequence)):
       print(sequence[index])
   ```

   you should use:

   ```
   for item in iterable:
       print(item)
   ```